# How to get the same result as a "simple deform of a Join" when applying a "simple deform to a parent group"

Tags: modeling, parent

I am trying to do something I consider should be simple : I have an object "made of" other objects, and I try to apply a simple deform function (bend over an empty) on it.
For that I have 2 ways of doing :
first 1 join all my objects. The result looks fine, but the final shape being considered as a complex polygon, the file explodes in size[image: before the bending].
second, I just decide that the basic shape is the parent of all the shapes and I apply my simple deform to it, after having set the same origin to all the elements. It ends as a total catastrophy, the parts flying in a big mess and loosing the whole coordination stuff.
[image: after the bending]
My question is simple: What Am I missing? why is a simple deform not applying the same way when objects are parents with the same origin defined?
My spheres are not sticking to the model as they should...

Comment: Probably relevant here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data

Comment: nope sorry, I'm really on a static problem, with everything applied EXCEPT the simple deform. And if I apply it, result is the same.